# Two sum algorithm in Ruby runtime won't pass on LeetCode

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash

I am trying to get a two-sum algorithm to pass on LeetCode and am running into a time constraint causing it to fail.

I'm not sure how to make my code faster to get it to pass. In the problem I am given an array of integers (nums) and a target value  that two numbers from the nums array must sum to.  Once those numbers are found, return their index values in the form of an array.

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  numbers_hash = Hash[(0...nums.size).zip(nums)]
  numbers_hash.delete_if do |k, v|
    key_indicies = ((numbers_hash.select { |ki,vi| vi == (target - v) }.keys) - [k])
    key_indicies.empty? ? true : (return [k, key_indicies].flatten)
  end
  return "Couldn't find target value"
end
```

I could keep the original nums array and do a loop inside a loop with `delete_if` to modify the iterated array and return if the correct target value is found.  I would prefer to use the hash approach as it is more readable, and I don't think the time constraint was that much to convert an array to a hash.

Answer (score 7):

The reason people pointed out the trouble with ternaries, is it usually indicates you're overcomplicating a process. You're checking if it's nil. In trying to minimize your usage of lines though, you make your own code much more difficult to read, and while it may "work" when integrated into a more complex code structure, would be an absolute nightmare even to yourself to later read.

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
    search = {}
    nums.each_with_index do |num,i| 
      return [search[target-num], i] unless search[target-num].nil?
      search[num] = i 
    end
end
```

is much more easily understood and later review than this:

```
def two_sum(a,g)s={};a.each_with_index{|n,i|s[g-n]==nil ?s[n]=i:(return[s[g-n],i])}end
```

Even though, they're essentially the exact same.

Comment: instead of ```unless search[target-num].nil?``` you can use ```if search[target-num]```

Comment: @pankajdoharey completely subjective to your stylistic preference, I prefer this writing since the logic reads back clearly like plain English for me. Everyone has their own preference though, and I appreciate you adding this alternative.

Comment: I just wanna say this is the best algorithm here and the fastest among others.

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about it for a while I realized I was approaching the problem from the wrong direction.  Instead of building a potentially giant hash table to begin with, I should add elements to the hash table one by one, each time checking if a solution exists before adding the new key:value

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  numbers_hash = {}
  nums.each_with_index do |number, index|
    numbers_hash[index] = number
    hash_key = ((numbers_hash.select { |k,v| v == (target - number) }.keys) - [index])
    hash_key.empty? ? false : (return [hash_key, index].flatten)
  end
  return "Couldn't find target value"
end
```

This runs much quicker than my previous solution.

Comment: Is this the answer? If not, it shouldn't have been added; SO isn't a discussion forum, and answers are for just that, answers. If it IS to be the selected answer, then wait and SO will time out and let you select it. `hash_key.empty? ? false : (return [hash_key, index].flatten)` isn't good Ruby. Try to make it more readable/maintainable. Ternary expressions are no faster than regular `if`/`then`/`else`, they're just harder to read.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the problem. I understand that ternary operators run no faster than standard if/else statements I just didn't know ternary operators were considered poor Ruby.  Thanks for the heads up and the editing of the original question.

Comment: @SeanSzurko sorry to revive an old question, but this question pops up high on google when searching for information related to this common ruby problem. I wanted to provide a thorough answer, and a basic explanation for best practices. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

See my solution below: it is more efficient i.e. 292 ms faster than 25.43% of all Ruby submissions for two-sum and uses 9.5MB less than 100 % of all Ruby submissions. It's worth taking a look. It's simple.

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
    nums.each_with_index do |num,index|
       if nums.include?(target - num)
           return [index,nums.find_index(target - num)] if index != nums.find_index(target - num)
       end
    end         
end
```

See details from LeetCode [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to use a hash. I would use two `each_with_index` and loop through the `nums` array

```
def two_sums(nums, target)
  nums.each_with_index do |num1, idx1|
    nums.each_with_index do |num2, idx2|
      next if idx1 == idx2
      return [idx1, idx2] if num1 + num2 == target
    end
  end
  return "Couldn't find target value"
end
```

Comment: This still fails due to time constraint I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```rb
def two_sum(nums, target)
  nums.each_with_index do |num, index|
    result = target - num
    position = nums.index(result)
    return [index, position] if position && (position != index)
  end
end
```

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation for what you did and why, so that the author can better understand your answer